# Jasper reports rowspan dynamic data

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm a newbie in jasper reports. I have table like this:

[image]

You can see at row 1:
c1, c2, c3 has duplicate value (AAA).
And I wanna include three columns and the result will be like bellow:

[image]

I hope in this case you can help me.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

If you have the same problem, please using **printWhenExpression** inside **reportElement** tag.

Comment: Wich element did you set **printWhenElement** attribute? and what is the boolean expression?

Comment: @Luc how we can merge the blank row when we use printWhenExpression